# Regex for a pattern

Tags: java, regex, notepad++

I want to write a regex for this below pattern.

```
of John at /roger/adam/sam
```

here John is a value(can be alphanumeric) and /roger/adam/sam is an XPath with can change.

I want to replace all such instances with

```
of $value at $XPath
```

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: you need to do that in java code, or inside notepad++? your tags are ambiguous

Comment: think you mean this `\bof [A-Za-z\d]+ at [a-zA-Z\d]+(?:/[a-zA-Z\d]+)+`

Comment: I have a word file and i need to replace all such occurences with that pattern. For example 

of John at /roger/adam/sam
of Tom123 at /roger/scot/thomas

should be replced with

of $value at $XPath
of $value at $XPath

Comment: Java program, in Notepad++, or in a Word doc? I have no idea what exactly it is you're asking.

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks.. it's working but after "of" it's just searching only single numeral character.

Comment: Well - here's a regex that'll match groups for the (most of) bits you want to replace. Wouldn't be able to help much more without more detail. `of (\S+)\sat ((?:\/\.\.|\/\.|\/\w+|\/\@\w+)+)`, note it doesn't account for xpath regular expressions, or anything besides basic path names

Comment: @jdphenix Awesome... It's working.. thanks a lot.. Just one more small issue.. It's not searching for xpath like /roger/adam[1]/sam, In such cases it's just searching till /roger/adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match

```
(of\s*)[a-zA-Z\d:-]+(\s*at\s*).*?(?=\s)
```

and replace with `$1$value$2$XPath`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iX2fB9/5)

Comment: It's working but it's just matching a single numeral cahracter after "of" .. Can you please modify a bit.. TIA

Comment: you mean.. it should be alphanumeric and not just digits?.. Please give an example of what to match and what not to..

Comment: Yes @karthik.. 
Example:
of John at /roger/adam/sam.. 
here John can be ABC, ABC123 or any value

Comment: Given pattern matches ABC, ABC123, etc.. What should it not match?

Comment: It's giving me entire document. Probably the '*' at the end is giving the whole document.

Comment: It's not taking pure numerals at "John"

Comment: Sorry to trouble you so much @karthik.... It's not working for 2011-01-01 or 08:00:00 or ABC-01-01 :(

Comment: @Abizer .. you know.. alphanumeric does not include `-`.. :P Check updated answer :)

Comment: Also.. you can add characters to include while matching in `[a-zA-Z\d:-]` in the above regex :)